# Installed Elementary OS not booting to desktop

Tags: install, release-jolnir

I’ve installed 6.1 on my 2015 MacBook Pro that previously was running Fedora- the installer works fine, but the desktop won’t boot.

There’s what appears to be extremely minuscule text in the upper left of the screen but it’s so small I can’t read it

I’m not able to reach a tty to look at logs or anything

Any additional troubleshooting steps I can take?

EDIT: I used LiveCD to look in the logs- it looks like there's no `/var/log/dmesg`, and the `journal` is empty also. I assume this mean something is going drastically wrong during boot

```
[liveuser@localhost-live log]$ sudo ls -ltr
total 136
drwx------. 2  115 root   4096 Jan 19  2020 speech-dispatcher
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   4096 Apr 24  2020 cups
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   4096 Apr 12  2021 lightdm
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   4096 Jul 19  2021 openvpn
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root   43      0 Dec 18 16:00 wtmp
-rw-------. 1 root root      0 Dec 18 16:00 ubuntu-advantage.log
drwx------. 2 root root   4096 Dec 18 16:00 private
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root   43      0 Dec 18 16:00 lastlog
drwxr-sr-x. 2 root  101   4096 Dec 18 16:00 journal
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root   4096 Dec 18 16:00 hp
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      0 Dec 18 16:00 fontconfig.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      0 Dec 18 16:00 faillog
-rw-rw----. 1 root   43      0 Dec 18 16:00 btmp
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      0 Dec 18 16:00 bootstrap.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    772 Apr 13 01:10 alternatives.log
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   4096 Apr 13 01:11 apt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 100979 Apr 13 01:11 dpkg.log
[liveuser@localhost-live log]$ sudo ls -ltr journal/
total 0
```

Answer (score 0):

After hearing that this worked fine on someone else's same MBP model and year on a reddit thread, I decided to retry without encryption, and it booted successfully!